# Insert deleted rows in trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

I need to insert the deleted rows from table Table_A to Table_B which have the same structure
(something like recycle bin) but i don't have much experience in SQL SERVER Triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Table_A_Delete_Instead_Of_Trigger
ON dbo.Table_A
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN    
     INSERT INTO Table_B 
     SELECT T 

     DELETE T                  
END
```

please spare my lake of experience. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need an 'INSTEAD OF' trigger, you need an 'AFTER' trigger.

Given a table TableA...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [Col1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Col2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and a corresponding TableB...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
    [Col1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Col2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then the following trigger will do what you wish:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_TableA_Archive 
ON  TableA
AFTER DELETE
AS 

    INSERT INTO TableB
    SELECT *
    FROM deleted
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Table_A_Delete_Instead_Of_Trigger
ON dbo.Table_A
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN    
     INSERT INTO Table_B 
     SELECT * FROM 
     DELETED;          
END
```

I think you don't need an instead of trigger in this case.